# I can only see a portion of my screen in the gui

Tags: unity, display, screen

My son was doing something on the machine and he made the GUI unusable.
It appears to be zoomed in so much that I only see a portion of the screen.
There is a taskbar on the left with enormous icons.
I can select some items from the taskbar, but I can only see a portion of the windows that pop up.
I can't even get a terminal window to pop up.

Is there a fix for this?
Is there a "safe mode" type way to boot to only get a command prompt and bypass the gui to debug this?

I think this is 14.04.2LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that he somehow changed the resolution of the display and maybe the scale of the items displayed as well.

If you can see the settings button in the top right corner, navigate to System Settings > Displays and change the resolution. You'll probably want the highest resolution listed there. After that, change the scale to 1.

If that is impossible or turns out to be incredibly difficult, you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, which should get a terminal open. Whether or not it shows up in your zoomed-in version of the display, however, is unknown to me. If that doesn't work, you can get a command line from the GRUB boot menu, by selecting Advanced boot options for Ubuntu, and then pressing <kbd>C</kbd>. Once you have the terminal open, you can try this command:

```
$ rm ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

which should reset your resolution. After that, you need to restart your computer and you still should go to the System Settings > Displays menu and make sure that the Scale for menus and title bars is set to 1.

Hope that helped.

Comment: You could also use Alt + F7 and the arrow keys to move the app around until you find the correct settings

Comment: Thank you Billy and Rumesh.  Removing the monitors.xml did not fix it.  But by doing the Alt+F7 trick I was able to scroll down to the setting that had been changed.  The setting was the Scale for menus and title bars was set all the way to 4.  When I returned it back to 1 the issue was fixed.